# Short story about a woman diver on a dangerous alien planet

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this story in a German adaption/translation of Asimov's Science Fiction, probably in the 90s.

The protagonist is a young woman on an aquatic alien planet with a permanent human population living largely in poverty. She works as a diver in the ocean (which is full of extremely dangerous wildlife), for interstellar tourists, either as a guide or in finding rare specimens which the tourists buy. Her dream is to leave the planet, and she achieves it at the end of the story, after a particularly dangerous job.

Comment: C'mon man - you just ruined the ending!

Answer (score 4):

"The Tuvela"(Demon Breed) by James Schmidt has a woman diver on an aquatic alien planet with dangerous wildlife.

But it is a alien invasion story.

[Link to the Story](http://arthursbookshelf.com/sci-fi/schmitz/The%20Demon%20Breed%20-%20James%20Schmitz.pdf)

Comment: Thanks, but it's much longer and also older than the story I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds a bit like the novella "Turquoise Days" by Alastair Reynolds.  There's an aquatic world with an impoverished/isolated human population. There's a female protagonist making a living diving with and researching some very dangerous life forms on behalf of off-worlders (scientists, though, rather than tourists).  She longs to leave and in the end, there's an 'escape', but it's not by leaving the planet.

So...close, but perhaps not on the mark.

Comment: Sounds very close at first, but the furter details of the story aren't anything like what I remember.